# How can I view unformatted RSS XML in a browser?

Tags: browser, rss, xml

The IE7 option of unchecking the box in `tools/content/settings` is no longer working for me, weirdly enough.

Does anyone have any other ideas how I can see the unformatted XML in either IE, FF3, or Chrome? (It seems like there must be a FF plugin, but can't seem to find one)

Answer (score 5):

View source?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in Firefox

Comment: view source does not show unformatted xml. It shows unindented code where all of the "<" and ">" are replaced with &Gt blah blah blah. no good, but thanks.

Comment: Works for me... In Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried viewing the page source?

Answer (score 3):

If view source doesn't do the trick for you, you could install the [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) plugin for IE and see the full request / response as raw data. It's a very handy tool- most web developers should install it.

Comment: Well, its not perfect, but much better. Fiddler still doesn't show me the truly raw xml - like View Source, it is converting the <> into &gt, etc. However, the XML tab did allow me to to see all of the nodes in the xml feed which is what I needed, since most of the nodes don't show up in the formatted version. So...Thanks!

Eric

Comment: Most of Fiddler's inspectors show you exactly the bytes flowing across the wire. If you see &gt, that's because that's what's flowing across the wire. The "XML" inspector will do XML-entity decoding.

Comment: @ericgr: I suspect you're talking about HTML embedded within the RSS. But, that's how RSS works - unlike Atom (which supports namespaced XHTML directly) HTML markup has to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Firebug Plugin for FireFox, it will show you everything you ever wanted to know about a document, right down to the POST and GETs and network traffic..